# Evaluate intergal $ I(\mu, \alpha, \lambda)=\int_{0}^{\infty} y^\mu e^{-\alpha (y+y^{-1})y^{\lambda}}dy. $

Tags: calculus, integration

Evaluate intergal 
$$
I(\mu, \alpha, \lambda)=\int_{0}^{\infty} y^\mu e^{-\alpha (y+y^{-1})y^{\lambda}}dy.
$$
It comes from phisics.

WolframAlpha gives partial answer 
$$
I(\mu, \alpha, 1)=\frac{1}{2} e^{-\alpha} \alpha^{-\frac{\mu}{2}-\frac{1}{2}} \Gamma \left( \frac{\mu+1}{2} \right) .
$$
It is possible to find it in close form?

Comment: without making any serious attempt to prove that, i suppose that the cases $\lambda=-1,0,1,3$ are the only ones which can be developed in a rather nice closed form (including Bessel functions)

Comment: @tired. I totally agree with you. But, even for $\lambda=3$, I arrive to some confluent hypergeometric function.

Comment: @ClaudeLeibovici i think at least for $\mu\in N$ they should be reduceable to Besselfunctions..but for nonintegers i think you are right